# Terms in the lambda calculus

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, lambda-calculus, formal-systems

The formal definition of the lambda calculus I am seeing [here](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/lambda-calculus/#Syn) reads:

> The class of $\lambda$-terms is defined inductively as follows:
>
> 1. Every variable is a $\lambda$-term.
> 2. If $M$ and $N$ are $\lambda$-terms, then so is $(M N)$.
> 3. If $M$ is a $\lambda$-term and $x$ is a variable, then $(\lambda x[M])$ is a $\lambda$-term.

Usually, the authors after similar definitions proceed to talk about expressions such as "$\lambda x. x + 2$", but I am not seeing any definition of the legal syntax for the terms $M, N, \dots$. From the inductive definition above, it seems I can only use "variables", but not even the symbol "$+$" in a term.

Is that because the $\lambda$-calculus is in fact not concerned with the actual expressions of $M, N \dots$?

Answer (score 4):

In order that expressions such as $\lambda x. x+2$ make sense in the $\lambda$-calculus (i.e. they are $\lambda$-terms), the expression $x+2$ should be a $\lambda$-term, according to your rule 3.

Actually, $x+2$ is a $\lambda$-term if it is interpreted as the expression $((+ \, x) 2)$ (i.e. two nested applications) where:

- $x$ is a variable;
- $+$ is the $\lambda$-term representing the arithmetic addition, i.e. $λm.λn.λf.λx.((m f) ((n f) x))$;
- $2$ is the $\lambda$-term representing the natural number 2, i.e. $\lambda f. \lambda x. (f(fx))$.

The idea is that $+$ and $2$ are just ''macros'' or shorthands for the $\lambda$-terms I wrote above.

For more information, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Arithmetic_in_lambda_calculus).

More in general, since the $\lambda$-calculus is Turing-complete, every [computable function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_function) on natural numbers can be represented by a $\lambda$-term, so any expression of the form $\lambda x_1. \dots \lambda x_n. f(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ can be seen as a  $\lambda$-term, provided that $f \colon \mathbb{N}^n \to \mathbb{N}$ is a computable function.

Comment: Yes, my gripe is that the "formal" inductive definition does not include your last 2 bullet points, which it should, if it were really "formal". Otherwise, I have no idea what "+" and "2" stand for.

Comment: But on the other hand, you might be able to say quite a few interesting things without ever specifying precisely the syntax of $\lambda$-terms. In that case, you would abstract out the actual semantics of the $\lambda$-terms and concern yourself only with how those $\lambda$-term interact, are equivalent, not equivalent, reducible to each other... I'm wondering which tack Church initially took.